# Servlet is getting executed without time intervel

Tags: java, servlets

I wrote a sevlet with the name AutoMail which send a mail notifcation for every 12 hrs.

And i intilaized "AutoMail" servelt in web.xml file like below.

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>AutoMail</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>com.org.AutoMail</servlet-class>
<load-on-startup>3</load-on-startup>
```

but this servlet is getting executed without any time intervels.

and i have some old servelts which are running in the same web conatiner.
Please tell me how to stop those servelts which are already running in background.

Thanks in Advance..

relevant code

```
    ApplicationContext context = WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(getServletContext());
    Timer timer = new Timer(); 
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yy"); 
    String currentdate = dateFormat.format(cal.getTime()); 
    long approvemail_duration = 1000*60*60*prevalencemail_hrs;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set load on startup parameter of the other servlets to 0 and restart the webapp and the old servlets won't autoload.

Where's the code for your timertask?

Comment: I have some other servelts are also running in my application which i gave the priority as 1,2,3..etc.. if i give 0 as status they wont load when i start the webapp

Comment: ApplicationContext context = WebApplicationContextUtils
    .getWebApplicationContext(getServletContext());Timer timer = new Timer();
  Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yy");
  String currentdate = dateFormat.format(cal.getTime());
  long approvemail_duration = 1000*60*60*prevalencemail_hrs;